# Proguard error when building AOSP with external jar files

Tags: android, jar, android-source, android-proguard

I use some external jar files in AOSP/framework/opt, and it is ok to mm -B those jar files and android framework, but when I try to use make -j4 to produce images,
it warns that library class depends on program class, and then it fails to make.
And the error is 'Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called'.
How to solve this problem?